# what is default Ip routing in mininet after creating topology and adding hosts?

Tags: mininet, opendaylight, openflow

I have just started working with mininet and opendaylight.
Iam trying to push MPLS services in nodes,but by default hosts are able to ping each other.

How they are able to ping without configuring nodes?

I don't understand this

Answer (score 2):

Which feature(s) have you installed? If you have installed l2switch,
then that would explain why the hosts are able to ping each other.
l2switch tries to emulate the spanning tree protocol and will install
flows to allow reach-ability to all hosts.